# Java, parse string 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss' to ZonedDateTime without changing time

Tags: java, spring-boot, timezone, simpledateformat, zoneddatetime

I have a string "2018-07-24T01:30:27". I want to parse this into ZonedDateTime with EST timezone without changing the time.

I have the code...

```
String foo = "2018-07-24T01:30:27";
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");

SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
return simpleDateFormat.parse(foo).toInstant().atZone(zone);
```

The return value is

```
2018-07-24T02:30:27-04:00[America/New_York]
```

I've tried creating this class as well, but it didn't help

```
@Configuration
public class TimeZoneConfig {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));

        System.out.println("Date in UTC: " + new Date().toString());
    }
}
```

Could I get some advice on this please?

Comment: You have `DateTimeFormatter` in [`java.time`](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro). You don't need to use `SimpleDateFormat` anymore.

Comment: I got an "Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor" error when I tried to switch. I think it's because my string doesn't have timezone information in it? LocalDateTime.parse works, but not ZonedDateTime.parse.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. But you can assign a zone to the formatter with `withZone`.

Comment: (1) Don’t mix old and modern. When you can use java.time, the modern Jvaa date and time API (`ZoneId` and `ZonedDateTime`), stay away from the outdated `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. (2) Don’t set nor rely on the default time zone of the JVM. It can be changed to something else from any other part of your program and any other program running in the same JVM. (3) Don’t rely on three letter time zone abbreviations like EST. They tend to be ambiguous. EST may mean Australian Eastern Standard Time and North American Eastern Standard Time, none of which are time zones (America/New_York is one).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime                               // Represents a date with a time-of-day, but lacks a time zone or offset-from-UTC.
.parse( "2018-07-24T01:30:27" )             // Returns a `LocalDateTime`.
.atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) )  // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
```

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

## Use concrete classes in *java.time*

The [Answer by michalk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63019262/642706) is correct but a bit obtuse. It uses the [`TemporalAccessor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAccessor.html) interface explicitly. Generally in Java, this would be a good thing. But the *java.time* classes were designed for app authors to call the concrete classes rather than the interfaces. To quote the Javadoc:

> This interface is a framework-level interface that should not be widely used in application code. Instead, applications should create and pass around instances of concrete types, such as LocalDate. There are many reasons for this, part of which is that implementations of this interface may be in calendar systems other than ISO. See ChronoLocalDate for a fuller discussion of the issues.

### `LocalDateTime`

So let’s do that. First, parse the input as a `LocalDateTime`. This class does not represent a moment, is not a point on the timeline, because it lacks the context of a time zone or offset.

```
String input = "2018-07-24T01:30:27" ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

### `ZonedDateTime`

Provide the context of a time zone.

```
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( zone ) ;
```

### `Instant`

If you want to see that same moment adjusted into UTC, extract a `Instant` object.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

## Don’t mess with default time zone

> TimeZone.setDefault

Do not set the JVM’s current default time zone except as a last resort. Doing so affects all code in all threads of all apps within that JVM.

Instead, write your *java.time* code to explicitly specify the desired/expected time zone. Never omit the optional time zone or offset from the various methods.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: This is gold: *Never omit the optional time zone or offset from the various methods.* Thank you for a well written and thorough answer.

Answer (score 4):

Since you want `ZonedDateTime` consider using `DateTimeFormatter` from `java.time` :

```
String foo = "2018-07-24T01:30:27";
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
        
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
TemporalAccessor temporalAccessor = dateTimeFormatter.withZone(zone).parse(foo);
return ZonedDateTime.from(temporalAccessor);
```

The returned `ZonedDateTime` will be :

```
2018-07-24T01:30:27-04:00[America/New_York]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    String foo = "2018-07-24T01:30:27";
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");

    ZonedDateTime result = LocalDateTime.parse(foo).atZone(zone);
    
    System.out.println(result);
```

When you know how, it is this simple. Output is:

> 2018-07-24T01:30:27-04:00[America/New_York]

Messages:

1. Your string is in ISO 8601 format. The classes of java.time parse the most common variants of ISO 8601 natively, without any explicit formatter. So we don’t need one.
2. Don’t mix old and modern. When you can use java.time, the modern Java date and time API (`ZoneId` and `ZonedDateTime`), stay away from the `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. BTW stay way from them in any case. `SimpleDateFormat` is a notorious troublemaker of a class.
3. Don’t set nor rely on the default time zone of the JVM.

   1. You are affecting all other parts of your program and all other programs running in the same JVM, probably adversely.
   2. The default time zone can be changed to something else from any other part of your program and any other program running in the same JVM, so may not stay what you set it to.

### What went wrong in your program?

`SimpleDateFormat` assumed that the string was in the default time zone of the JVM, so converted from that time zone. Next you converted to America/New_York (Eastern Daylight Time or EDT) thus changing the hour of day correspondingly.

Why setting the default time zone of your JVM didn’t work is that `TimeZone` takes EST, Eastern *Standard* Time, literally (opposite what it does with CST and PST), but in July New York is on Eastern *Daylight* Time, so there is still a conversion happening. But as I said, you don’t want to set the default time zone anyway.

### Link

[Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)